# Creating Two Level List Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here's a brain tickler that I have been trying to solve for a couple of hours.  The code below takes two lists of integers and returns a list of the items in the 1st list but not the second AND the items in the 2nd list that are not in the first.

```
def difference(lista, listb):
    output_list = []
    for element in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[element] not in listb:
            output_list.append(lista[element])
    for element in range(len(listb)):
        if listb[element] not in lista:
            output_list.append(listb[element])
    return output_list

list1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
```

print(f"\nYour lists are {list1} and {list2}, the items in the first, but not in the second.")

The code works, but I am sure there is a way to do this with list comprehension.  I have tried:

`output_list = [element for element in lista if element not in listb] + [element for element in listb if element not in lista]`

This doesn't work.  Any clues very gratefully received!

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* - It does.

Comment: Thank you...I had put my return statement in the wrong place...doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, u can do this in various ways:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
```

using list comprehension:

```
[x for x in list1 if x not in list2] + [y for y in list2 if y not in list1]
```

using python's set + ord:

```
list(set(list1) ^ set(list2))
```

using the python's filter function:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x not in list2, list1)) + list(filter(lambda x: x not in list1, list2))
```

using python's map function:

```
from_1 = list(map(lambda x: x if x not in list2 else None, list1))
from_2 = list(map(lambda x: x if x not in list1 else None, list2))
output = [x for x in from_1 + from_2 if x is not None]
```

or even using `itertools.chain`:

```
[item for item in chain(list1, list2) if (item in list1 and item not in list2) or (item in list2 and item not in list1)]
```

Comment: The last one could use `if (item in list1) != (item in list2)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

If duplicate items in the lists are not an issue & ordering is not an issue, this can be solved using sets. For example

```
list1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 9]

def difference(lista, listb):
    
    res_a = set(list1).difference(list2)
    res_b = set(list2).difference(list1)
    
    print(f"list1: {res_a}")
    print(f"list2: {res_b}")
```

Output:

```
difference(list1, list2)

>> list1: {4, 6}
>> list2: {7, 9}
```

Comment: This also presumes order doesn't matter. It also doesn't combine both outputs into a single output, where `set(list1).symmetric_difference(list2)` would do that as a single operation (while still discarding duplicates and ordering).

Comment: No single way solve this, all solutions are welcome. If you want to post a more simple or more concise solution, please do so.